# Getting process name with extension name(.exe per example)

Tags: c#, process

I'm making a program and I want to add all processes to a listbox, for this, I used the following code:

```
foreach(Process p in Process.GetProcesses())
{
   listBox1.Items.Add(p.ProcessName);
}
```

This adds the processes name like

[image: Process List]

But instead, I would like to see the processes with their extensions for example:
chrome.exe or iexplorer.exe as there are some programs that aren't .exe like *XTrap.xt*

Edit: I also tried

```
listBox1.Items.Add(p.ModuleMain.FileName);
```

But it throws a `Win32Exception: Access Denied`

Comment: You can get a Win32Exception if a 32-bit process tries to inspect the main module of a 64 bit process.  Is that what is happening in your case?  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.mainmodule(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @EricJ. I don't know but it might be, my windows is 64bit..

Comment: @L3n: Make sure your program is set to build as a 64-bit program.  Also, make sure you run as Administrator (as user-level access is probably not sufficient to inspect details of some processes).

Comment: @EricJ. How do I set the app to x64?Like this: postimg.org/image/a694w40pv ?But now it's weird, if I build and run as admin in the bin folder(outside VS) it throws me the same exception but when I click continue it shows me the path of the files like: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Chrome\chrome.exe" and I would like to just get chrome.exe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the app to run as x64 and as admin user, right click run as or run VS as admin.

You can use  Path.GetFileName(p.ModuleMain.FileName) to get filename from full path.

Comment: How do I set the app to x64?Like this: http://postimg.org/image/a694w40pv/ ?But now it's weird, if I build and run as admin in the bin folder(outside VS) it throws me the same exception but when I click continue it shows me the path of the files like: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Chrome\chrome.exe" and I would like to just get chrome.exe

Comment: @L3n `Path.GetFileName` will be your friend then.

Comment: Use Path.GetFileName(path) method to get filename :-)

Comment: @whoisj when I type Path. it doesn't recognize!What do I have to type in "using"?

Comment: Now I can use Path but it throws the exception still: http://postimg.org/image/id14noqsj/

Comment: im not quite sure, but it may be happening per module, so wrap the add in a try catch and continue